# почему не работает curl post запрос?

Tags: php

Делаю отправку CURL запроса, а в ответ получаю на странице получаю "resource(2) of type (Unknown)" в чем проблема?

```
<?php
    $city2 = 22;
    $data = array($city2);
    $url = "тутссылкаset2.php";
    $post = ''.$city2.'';
    $headers = ['Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 2
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('city2' => 22)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 2
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http:тутссылка');
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);   
    var_dump($ch);  
    ?>
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_VERBOSE TRUE` поставь - может поможет найти проблему

Answer (score 1):

[curl_close](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-close.php) согласно документации "завершает сеанс cURL и освобождает все ресурсы. Дескриптор ch также уничтожается.", поэтому var_dump возвращает вам ошибку.
Если хотите посмотреть, что возвращается, то надо так

```
$returned = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);   
var_dump($returned);
```